# Different functionalities depending movement of the Qt slider

Tags: c++, qt

I have a vertical slider and I want to do something depending on how the slider is being moved.

a. If the user moves the slider by clicking I want to do something when the slider is released.

b. If the user moves the slider with the scroll, I want to do something when it stops scrolling.

c. If the user moves the slider by pressing the arrow key, I want to do something every time the number changes.

I haven't found a way to capture all these functionalities.

With

```
void on_verticalSlider_slice_sliderReleased() {
  qDebug() << "on_verticalSlider_slice_sliderReleased";
  qDebug() << this->Internals->verticalSlider_slice->value();
}
```

it only captures the first option. Nothing with scrolling or arrow key.

With

```
void on_verticalSlider_slice_valueChanged(int value){
    qDebug() << "on_verticalSlider_slice_valueChanged";
    qDebug() << value;
}
```

it captures the arrow keys and scrolling, but it also captures click and release, going trought every number, same with scrolling.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve can be accomplished by using the Qt's event system: https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html

Here's a rough pseudocode:

```
bool MySlider::event(QEvent *event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) {
      // This is key event
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::MousePress) {
      // This is mouse press event
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::Scroll) {
      // This is scroll event
    } else {

    }

    // If you want your slider to change the value based on the event instead of
    // you manually setting your slider's value based on the above events.
    return QSlider::event(event);
}
```

Comment: Great! But I'm getting ` error: use of undeclared identifier 'mySlider'`. I added the slider with QtDesigner.  I don't know what more I need.

Comment: Hi. My bad. I assumed you Sub classed QSlider for your purposes. (MySlider was supposed to be your subclassed QSlider).

You can either Subclass a QSlider, extend it with the signals you want, and use that in your UI ( https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html ).

OR

You can install an event filter on the existing slider in your code: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter . Something like `SliderMonitor`, to track slider value changes + events that are sent to the slider and emit signals like `valueChangedByScroll()` , `valueChangedByKeyPress()` etc..;